# On the asymptotic character of a certain sum involving the Mobius function

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Let $\mu$ represet the Mobius function. If i recall correctly, i heard a few years ago that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mu(n)e^{-n/x} =\Omega_{\pm}(x^{1/2})$. Can someone help in proving this, or provide a reference of the proof ?

Comment: I don't know a reference where this is proved, but this should follow from the methods of Chapter 15 of Montgomery-Vaughan.

Comment: Indeed, precisely this estimate is given as exercise 4(c) in section 15.1 of Montgomery and Vaughan.